# Error:(497) Attribute "navigationMode" already defined with incompatible format

Tags: android

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
}


Error:(497) Attribute "navigationMode" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(497) Attribute "displayOptions" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(506) Attribute "layout_scrollFlags" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(511) Attribute "actionBarSize" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(515) Attribute "collapsedTitleGravity" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(515) Attribute "expandedTitleGravity" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(516) Attribute "layout_collapseMode" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(518) Attribute "buttonTintMode" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(520) Attribute "layout_anchorGravity" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(523) Attribute "fabSize" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(526) Attribute "showDividers" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(530) Attribute "showAsAction" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(544) Attribute "tabMode" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(544) Attribute "tabGravity" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(549) Attribute "backgroundTintMode" already defined with incompatible format.

Error:(7, 5) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(12, 5) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(52, 5) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(82, 5) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(204, 5) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(216, 5) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(188, 5) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(230, 5) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(242, 5) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(270, 5) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(279, 5) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(286, 5) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(336, 5) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(340, 5) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(382, 5) Original attribute defined here.
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Admin-PC\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Im facing this issue can anyone tell me why im getting this error and how can i sole this error.
i try changing "Dependencies API Version - ex. 26.0.0-alpha1,25.0.1,25.0.2,25.1.1,24.0.2 etc)

Comment: Did you used any other library? Can you please add your activity codes?

Comment: What class your Activities are  extending?

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   protected void onCreate(Bundle var1) {
      super.onCreate(var1);
      this.setContentView(2130968601);
      Utility.setToolBar(this, true);
      RecyclerView var2 = (RecyclerView)this.findViewById(2131558509);